# Являются ли эти слова причастиями или другой частью речи?

Tags: прилагательные, морфология

задолжавшийся и заложившийся
из романа Достоевского "Идиот"

Answer (score 1):

Даже без контекста видно, что оба эти слова - действительные причастия прошедшего времени

Comment: Судя по суффиксу - да. Но, возможно, в роли существительного.